# Displaying a report with JS: How to check if a report exist?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

Is there a convenient was to check if a report with the given report name exists using JavaScript?

Following [this](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/reporting/doc/ic3OpenReport.php) official guide on how to display a report I managed to display a report with the name given in the URL. If the given report name does not match a report I get a error:

```
Could not open successfully the report 'fake-name' (The report '/shared/fake-name.icc-report (null)' does not exists.)
```

So I want to redirect the user if the report does not exists and for that I need something like a function that gives me true or false based on the report name.

Is there any way this can be done?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using these options to have access to openReport callback:

```
var options = {

        root: ic3root,
        rootLocal: ic3rootLocal,
        imagesPath: 'images',

        //librariesMode:'dev',

        callback: function () {

            $('#intro').remove();

            var ic3reporting = new ic3.Reporting(
                    {
                        noticesLevel: ic3.NoticeLevel.ERROR,

                        dsSettings: {
                            url: "http://<your_domain>/icCube/gvi"
                        }
                    });

            ic3reporting.setupGVIConfiguration(function () {
                ic3reporting.setupApplication(
                        {
                            mode: ic3.MainReportMode.REPORTING,
                            hideTopPanel: true,
                            noticesLevel: ic3.NoticeLevel.ERROR,
                            container: $("#container")
                        });

                ic3reporting.openReport({
                    report: {
                        name: 'shared/report23'
                    }
                }, function (reportState) {
                    var reportExists = _.isEmpty(ic3reporting.reportName());
                })

            });
        }
    };

    ic3ready(options);
```

You may want to redirect user in case "reportExists" equals to false